# Chronology of Ray Bradbury's Martian short stories

Tags: short-stories, ray-bradbury, chronological-order

I checked out an anthology of all of Bradbury's work from the library and I love it! I especially like how many Mars stories seem to fit in a single narrative, like "Mars is Heaven" referencing "Earth Men", and maybe "Dark they were, and golden-eyed" fits in somewhere. Is there a good ordered list anywhere?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bradbury's collection *The Martian Chronicles* was supposed to be a chronological arrangement. For instance, in my copy, "The Earth Men" is the 4th story, dated August 1999, while "Mars Is Heaven", under the alternative title "The Third Expedition", comes 6th, dated April 2000. I would say, then, that the [table of contents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Chronicles) of *The Martian Chronicles* is your good list.

You can use the [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi) to find out about variant titles; e.g., if you click on the title "The Third Expedition" on [this page](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?333200)
you'll find that it's a variant title for "Mars Is Heaven!".

**Edit.** To save this from being a "link-only" answer, here is the chronological list from Wikipedia. There are two alternative years for each story to take place, because the dates were moved 31 years futureward for a 1997 edition. I've added Internet Archive links for the pulp magazine stories.

> [Rocket Summer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58426) (January 1999/2030), [*Planet Stories*, Spring 1947](https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_v03n06_1947-Spring#page/n45/mode/1up)
> [Ylla](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64825) (February 1999/2030) aka "I'll Not Look for Wine", [*Avon Fantasy Reader* No. 14, 1950](https://archive.org/stream/Avon_Fantasy_Reader_14_1950_C2C/Avon%20Fantasy%20Reader%2014%20%281950%29%20%28C2C%29#page/n21/mode/1up)
> [The Summer Night](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58437) (August 1999/2030) aka "The Spring Night", [*The Arkham Sampler*, Winter 1949](https://archive.org/stream/arkhamsampler5winter1949#page/n35/mode/1up)
> [The Earth Men](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58375) (August 1999/2030), [*Thrilling Wonder Stories*, August 1948](https://archive.org/stream/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v32n03_1948-08#page/n68/mode/1up)
> [The Taxpayer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58438) (March 2000/2031)
> [Mars Is Heaven!](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58440) (April 2000/2031) aka "The Third Expedition", [*Planet Stories*, Fall 1948](https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_Canadian_Ed._v03n12_1948-Fall#page/n58/mode/1up)
> [—And the Moon Be Still as Bright](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58365) (June 2001/2032), [*Thrilling Wonder Stories*, June 1948](https://archive.org/stream/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v32n02_1948-06_images_/Thrilling%20Wonder%20Stories%20v32n02%201948-06%20images%20#page/n77/mode/1up)
> [The Settlers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58429) (August 2001/2032)
> [The Green Morning](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58386) (December 2001/2032)
> [The Locusts](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58402) (February 2002/2033)
> [Night Meeting](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58412) (August 2002/2033)
> [The Shore](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58431) (October 2002/2033)
> [The Fire Balloons](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41401) (November 2002/2033) aka "In This Sign", [*Imagination*, April 1951](https://archive.org/stream/Imagination_v02n02_1951-04_cape1736#page/n56/mode/1up)
> [Interim](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58393) (February 2003/2034)
> [The Musicians](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58410) (April 2003/2034)
> [The Wilderness](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56012) (May 2003/2034), [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, November 1952](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v003n07_1952-11#page/n118/mode/1up)
> [Way in the Middle of the Air](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58448) (June 2003/2034), [*Other Worlds Science Stories*, July 1950](https://archive.org/stream/Other_Worlds_v02n01_1950-07.Clarkcape1736/Other%20Worlds%20v02n01%20%281950-07.Clark%29%28cape1736%29#page/n142/mode/1up)
> [The Naming of Names](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64808) (2004-05/2035-36)
> [Usher II](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64844) (April 2005/2036) aka "Carnival of Madness", [*Thrilling Wonder Stories*, April 1950](https://archive.org/stream/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v36n01_1950-04#page/n95/mode/1up)
> [The Old Ones](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58416) (August 2005/2036)
> [The Martian](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58406) (September 2005/2036) aka "Impossible", [*Super Science Stories*, November 1949](https://archive.org/stream/Super_Science_Stories_v06n01_1949-11#page/n71/mode/1up)
> [The Luggage Store](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58404) (November 2005/2036)
> [The Off Season](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58415) (November 2005/2036), [*Thrilling Wonder Stories*, December 1948](https://archive.org/stream/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v33n02_1948-12.Standard#page/n98/mode/1up)
> [The Watchers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58447) (November 2005/2036)
> [The Silent Towns](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58432) (December 2005/2036)
> [Dwellers in Silence](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58374) (April 2026/2057) aka "The Long Years", [*Planet Stories*, Spring 1949](https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_v04n02_1949-Spring#page/n52/mode/1up)
> [There Will Come Soft Rains](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40876) (August 4, 2026/2057)
> [The Million-Year Picnic](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?504661) (October 2026/2057), [*Planet Stories*, Summer 1946](https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_v03n03_1946-Su_sas#page/n96/mode/1up)

Comment: The version of "The Watchers" that you list above (WEIRD TALES, May 1945) is not the version that is in THE MARTIAN CHRONICLES. The latter is an entirely different story that concerns the return to Earth of the Martian colonists due to their witnessing an atomic war on their home planet. The version that you list above is actually one of Bradbury's horror stories for WEIRD TALES that happens to have the same name as the CHRONICLES story.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Fixed now. Added a couple more Archive links. Please let me know if you find any more mistakes.